# XPath for multiple predicates

Tags: xml, xpath, predicate, xpath-2.0

I have a XML for eg.

```
<a>
  <b>
    <c/>
    <c/>
    <c/>
  </b>
</a>
```

I would like to fetch only 1st and 3rd child of  tag:
To fetch a single child i'm using 
**XPATH** as`.//a/b/c[1]`
Can i fetch both [1] and [3] nodes with a single path without iterating over the parent node?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use this

```
.//a/b/c[position() = 1 or position() = 3]
```